# Google Apps Marketplace OpenID breaks when applying ssl

Tags: ssl, oauth, google-apps-marketplace

We are using OpenID Oauth 1.0 with the Google Apps Marketplace manifest (we will migrate to Oauth 2.0 eventually). Up until now our application didn't use SSL so the OpenID realm was http://*.domain.com. A few days ago we have applied SSL to the application so we have changed the OpenID realm to be https://*.domain.com.

This works well from existing installations, however for new installations we cannot get the permission to access the user calendar. (we get the same exceptions as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781173/google-apps-marketplace-authorization)). The SSO works just fine.

We are pretty stuck here since don't see what we do wrong and also we cannot understand how come the current manifest affects different domains differently.

**Update: Adding some code.**

Manifest:

```
<Extension id="realm" type="openIdRealm">
   <Url>https://*.domain.com</Url>
</Extension>
```

Authentication (.net)

```
openid.UseDirectedIdentity = true;
openid.TrustRoot = "https://*.domain.com";
AttributeExchange ax = new AttributeExchange(openid);
ax.AddFetchItem(AttributeExchangeSchema.Email, 1, true);
ax.AddFetchItem(AttributeExchangeSchema.FirstName, 1, true);
ax.AddFetchItem(AttributeExchangeSchema.LastName, 1, true);
providerUrl = googleXrds.FetchProviderUrlFromDomain(userDomain);
openid.ProviderUrl = new Uri(providerUrl);
openid.CreateRequest();
```

Calendar request (.net):

```
CalendarService service = CreateOAuthService("user@userdomain.com");
CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
query.NumberToRetrieve = 10000;
query.OAuthRequestorId = "user@userdomain.com";
CalendarFeed resultFeed = service.Query(query);
```

Exception from calendar request:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full?max-results=10000&xoauth_requestor_id=sandy@retentiongrid.com
  Source=Google.GData.Client
  ResponseString=<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: ACL not found for domain: 680375875204 and consumer: 369586890486</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: ACL not found for domain: 680375875204 and consumer: 369586890486</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample code? Obfuscate any sensitive information of course.

Comment: @EricKoleda - added the relevant code.

Comment: To confirm, did you update your OpenID realm in your Google Apps Marketplace manifest as well as in your code?

Comment: Can you also check that no additional data access is being requested? https://support.google.com/a/answer/176367?hl=en

Comment: We have updated the OpenID realm in the Marketplace manifest as well as in our code.
We are requesting for Calendar (Read/Write) and Resources (Read). This part wasn't changed.

Comment: There is some evidence that this error may be related to problems with specific domains. Have you gotten this same error on multiple new domains, or just this one?

Comment: I have gotten this error for multiple new domains. I did screen share with 4 of them and verified the application was installed and permission was granted.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to debug the problem further. Our recommendation is to either revert back to non-SSL URLs or upgrade to OAuth2.